# How to chain/queue up functors?

Tags: c++, functor

I am not using C++11 (otherwise I would use lambdas)

I have iterators to an input data structure and output data structure. I want to do some operations on the input data and store the result in the output. Note that the start and end types may be different (int -> float for example).

I tried to model my function after the standard algorithms and gave it the following prototype

```
template<class INPUT_ITR, OUTPUT_ITR>
void f(INPUT_ITR in_it, INPUT_ITR in_it_end, OUTPUT_ITR out_it, ContextStuff)
```

The function does many different things depending on the context. Sometimes the function only needs to use one functor, so the line of code looks like this

```
transform(in_it, in_it_end, out_it, Functor1());
```

But sometimes the function wants to use a series of functors on each data element. Is there a way I can create a chain of functors as a single functor to use in transform? The functors for the chain will be known at compile type.

For example

```
transform(in_it, in_it_end, out_it, CHAIN(Functor1(), Functor2()));
```

Performs Functor1 on *in, then Functor2 on the result, then stores in *out.

I can inherit my functors from unary_function for the solution.

Comment: Might just be better to make a custom functor for it. Nothing really comes to mind, but I'll bet Boost has some tricks.

Comment: Without C++11 it's impossible to get a functor's result type without cooperation of the functor (usually `result_type`). So if you want to do this all your functors will have to have a `result_type` typedef.

Comment: @Fozi I can inherit my functors from unary_function for the solution.

Comment: Also, without C++11 most of the work you will be doing is going to be writing `CHAIN` macros and classes that forward various amounts of parameters.

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh ok, so only one parameter...

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.josuttis.com/cppcode/compose.html. Also, you can google compose_f_gx. I think this is pretty much what you want. Also, look at the boost::bind documentation. One can nest binds for functional composition (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind_as_compose.cpp).

Comment: @NeilKirk  I wish God helps those like you and me without lamdbas.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
template<class Callable1, class Callable2>
struct Chain : public std::unary_function<
    typename Callable2::argument_type, typename Callable1::result_type>
{
    Chain(const Callable1 &f1, const Callable2 &f2) : f1(f1), f2(f2) {}

    typename Callable1::result_type operator () (
           typename Callable2::argument_type param) 
    { 
        return f1(f2(param));
    }
private:
    Callable1 f1;
    Callable2 f2;
};

template<class Callable1, class Callable2>
Chain<Callable1, Callable2> chain(const Callable1 &f1, const Callable2 &f2) {
    return Chain<Callable1, Callable2>(f1, f2);
}
```

The Chain class is a functor that combines two other functors. Since it's a `unary_function` itself you should be able to combine it further. The `chain` function lets you create the `Chain` instance without having to worry about types.

Usage example: http://ideone.com/7QpmEU

Comment: operator() should be const, apart from that looks fine.

Comment: @WernerErasmus Note that f1's and f2's operators might not be const. Imagine a functor that calculates a sum or counts invocations. But yes I agree in most cases it should be const.

Comment: I see your point. Nevertheless, making them non-const would force algorithms to copy them. Otherwise I would at least consider a const overload for when Chain is passed by const&, or make them mutable, arguing that calling op() does not modify the logical state of Chain (true because there is no way for the user to get the result of the modification (sum). Also, algorithms like accumulate use the return value of the operation.

Comment: e.g: algo( const Func& f ){ f(); } //Fails!

Comment: @WernerErasmus Again, I agree with you. You can simply add a const version of the `operator ()` - the non-const version will not be considered in a const context and the const version will not compile with non-const f1()/f2(). However, as long as you use it with the standard libraries it is not required to be const. `std::for_each` explicitly allows non-const behavior, but `std::transform` requires "no side-effects". This does not mean const. Making it const is a good way to ensure that but it's not required, and if you look at my code above it does have no side-effects and works with both.